# SPARQL: how do you also return the entity and not only its propery?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I have the following query

```sql
SELECT ?animal ?timePregnant WHERE {
  wd:Q15083 wdt:P3063 ?timePregnant .
  SERVICE wikibase:label
  {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en"}
}
```

How do I make sure that it returns `giraffe` and `457` days? At the moment it is only returning an empty label for animal and then `457` for the days.

```sql
SELECT ?animal ?timePregnant WHERE {
  ?animal wdt:P3063 ?timePregnant .
  SERVICE wikibase:label
  {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en"}
}
```

I thought about trying something like this but for this it returns all entities. I need to add a second constraint but I do not know how I set the constraint that `?animal` is `Q15083`.

What is the constraint needed?

Comment: not sure what you think in your second query `wd:?animal` would do, but that is clearly illegal syntax

Comment: `SELECT ?animalLabel ?timePregnant WHERE{
  VALUES ?animal {wd:Q15083}
?animal wdt:P3063 ?timePregnant .
SERVICE wikibase:label
{bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en"}
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query returns all the animals IDs, their labels and their gestation periods:

```
SELECT ?animal ?animalLabel ?timePregnant WHERE{
  ?animal wdt:P3063 ?timePregnant .
  SERVICE wikibase:label
  {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en"}
}
```

If you want to limit the set of animals, you can use `VALUES ?animal { wd:Q15083 }` in this way:

```
SELECT ?animal ?animalLabel ?timePregnant WHERE{
  VALUES ?animal { wd:Q15083 }
  ?animal wdt:P3063 ?timePregnant .
  SERVICE wikibase:label
  {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en"}
}
```

Comment: yes thanks this is exactly what i meant for the second one. what exactly is it that VALUES does though?

Comment: @astroWolf Check [SPARQL 1.1 Query Language § 10.2.1 VALUES syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data)